# Sending nested data from google sheet to API

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, gupshup

I am trying to implement following REST in google script
[image: REST documentation]

Code I have used is as below

```js
function whatsapp() {
  //https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/whatsapp-api-documentation#SendText

  var payload = {"channel":"whatsapp", 
                  "source":"917834811114", 
                  "destination":"91999990**34",//I have * done it on purpose  
                  "src.name":"googlerishisheet", 
                 "message.payload" : {
                   "isHSM":"true",
                   "type": "text",
                   "text": "Hi John, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by 15 Feb"
                 }
                }
                 
                           
  var url = 'https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v1/msg?apikey=0*8e4a487d6d4d3ccd2d52e7f0ffb78f'; // I have done * on purpose
  var options = {"method" : "post",
                 "payload" : payload};
   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Result I am getting is

[image]

I have tried following ways also.

1. `"payload":JSON.stringify(payload)`
   Result - **{text=Hi John, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by 15 Feb, type=text, isHSM=false}**
2. `"message":{"payload" : { "isHSM":"false", "type": "text", "text": "Hi I am testing whatsapp" }}};` and set contentType to x-www.....urlencoded..

Result - **{payload={type=text,text=Hi I am testing whatsapp, isHSM=false}}**

3. `"src.name":"googlerishisheet", "message.payload.isHSM":"false", "message.payload.type": "text", "message.payload.text": "Hi I am testing whatsapp" };` 
   Result - **Same issue**

Comment: Tried that too, not working getting same following result _{text=Hi John, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by 15 Feb, type=text, isHSM=false}_

Comment: Now it is showing _{payload={type=text,text=Hi I am testing whatsapp, isHSM=false}}_

Comment: Already done this style also, but got same result

Comment: How about `var payload = {"channel":"whatsapp", 
                  "source":"917834811114", 
                  "destination":"91999990**34",//I have * done it on purpose  
                  "src.name":"googlerishisheet", 
                 "message.payload" : JSON.stringify({
                   "isHSM":"true",
                   "type": "text",
                   "text": "Hi John, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by 15 Feb"
                 })
                }` and `contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in options?

Comment: writing message.payload as follows done the trick. ` "message.payload":"{\"isHSM\":\"false\",\"text\":\"Testing message\",\"type\":\"text\"}" `  Taken this from [https://curl.trillworks.com/] which converts curl to json      ALSO    Just checked `contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ` is default in google script [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app]

Comment: JSON.stringify({ "isHSM":"true", "type": "text", "text": "Hi John, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by 15 Feb" }) **also worked**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation states that `message.payload` value is of type `object`. However, it seems you should send it as plain string, while maintaining the `payload` contentType as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

```
    "message.payload" : JSON.stringify({
                   "isHSM":"true",
                   "type": "text",
                   "text": "Hi John, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by 15 Feb"
                 })
```

Comment: I implemented this in Python using ```json.dumps``` thanks for the help @TheMaster

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add content type as well.

```
var options = {
                "method" : "post",
                "headers": {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
                 },
                 "payload" : payload
             };
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: Without headers also this thing i working, issue is not accepting nested data in this format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending this message as a template message, be sure that your template is approved by WhatsApp or the same template that you're using ("Hi {1}, your order is confirmed and will be delivered to you by {2}") is pre-approved by GupShup. You can check it in your Dashboard.